# Django - Charfield creates an item int my BD

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x

I have a simple project here, with two models that contain an attribute called **telefone** in both.

**telefone** is **phone** in portuguese.

Code

```
class Medico (models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    endereco = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    cpf = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=11)
    telefone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    especialidade = models.ForeignKey(Especialidade, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome

class Paciente (models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    endereco = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    cpf = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=11)
    telefone = models.CharField(max_length=15)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome
```

I did the makemigrations and migrate, everything worked as expected, I'm using MySQL as BD.

But for some reason, the phone field is int int in my BD for both the patient table and the medical table, see the image:

[image]

Now the other fields are correct, could anyone tell me why this is happening?

EDIT 01:

```
migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Paciente',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('nome', models.CharField(max_length=50)),
                ('endereco', models.CharField(max_length=60)),
                ('cpf', models.CharField(max_length=11, unique=True)),
                ('telefone', models.CharField(max_length=15)),
            ],
        ),
```

[image]

continue

[image]

Comment: Can you show the migration that added that field?

Comment: i edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete all the files in yourapp/migrations, except `__init__.py`

Then run these 2 commands  :

```
python manage.py makemigrations

python manage.py migrate
```

**UPDATE :**

If that does not work, delete all tables from MySQL database and let Django recreate them using `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: Yes but sometimes the existing `.py` files in migrations folder can cause issues

Comment: what about medico table ? is telefone varchar or also int ?

Comment: is varchar for table medico and paciente

Comment: The problem still exists, I delete all files with __init__.py exception

Comment: `__init__.py` should not be deleted. Just the create a new file called `__init__.py` in migrations folder and leave it empty. Now try this : `python manage.py makemigrations sistema` and `python manage.py migrate sistema`. I suppose that sistema is your app name

Comment: Are you sure that's the database you're working on ? Because it's weird that the fields are not altered even after migration. If that's the case then you might have to delete all tables from mysql and let Django recreate them.

Comment: yes i am sure, i tried delete all BD and create again, but i will try again.

Comment: Is working man, thank very much, can you do a answer  in this question?